# How to retrive string value of Long.MAX_VALUE in compile time in java?

Tags: java, string, spring, runtime, compile-time

Is there any possible way to setup constant compile time value using a runtime call method?
In "Spring in Action" book, I got this piece of code:

```
private static final String MAX_LONG_AS_STRING = Long.toString(Long.MAX_VALUE);

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Spittle> spittles(
        @RequestParam(value = "max", defaultValue = MAX_LONG_AS_STRING) long max,
        @RequestParam(value = "count", defaultValue = "20") int count) {
    return spittleRepository.findSpittles(max, count);
}
```

the problem is with MAX_LONG_AS_STRING, because defaultValue param needs to be a String constant but MAX_LONG_AS_STRING is not a constant compile time variable, is there any possible way to get Long max value as a constant String value? 
Maybe there is something which can help me to call toString method during compile time, or retrieve this value in any other way ?

Comment: `private static final String MAX_LONG_AS_STRING = "9223372036854775807";` ?

Comment: @bradimus this would be workaround. What if java will have bigger longs in future 128 - 256 bit systems?

Comment: @mlecz The contract for [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) specifies that it returns `2^63-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this as shown in the below steps:

(1) Get the Max value first `long MAXVALUE = Long.MAX_VALUE;`

(2) Set the `@RequestParam`  value as `defaultValue = MAXVALUE+""` (converts long to string)

**Complete Code:**

```
private static final long MAXVALUE = Long.MAX_VALUE;//Get the long value first

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void spittles(
            @RequestParam(value = "max", defaultValue = MAXVALUE+"") long max,
            @RequestParam(value = "count", defaultValue = "20") int count) {
       // return spittleRepository.findSpittles(max, count);
    }
```

Comment: As much as I hate `+""` instead of `toString` or `String.valueOf`, it may be needed here.

Comment: But why "Spring in Action" can ues MAX_LONG_AS_STRING?

Comment: you can first assign the value to MAX_LONG_AS_STRING and then can use. It's workable.
private static final String MAX_LONG_AS_STRING = "9223372036854775807";

Comment: No need to assign a variable to, Long.MAX_VALUE + "" on defaultValue is enough

Answer (score -3):

```
private static final String MAX_LONG_AS_STRING = String.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

could do the trick;

Comment: this won't work because String.valueOf is also a runtime call